# how to make a small change in a deployed Spring boot app without re-deploying the whole fat jar file?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a weak internet connection so copying the Spring boot fat jar to my Linux server is time consuming. I use FileZilla to copy my jar file to my Linux server even if I change only a single line of code. Is there a better way. Is there a way I could send only the class I change to the server not the whole thing. Or is there an easier way to do it like with HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: 1. You can push your code to GitHub repository.    
2. Have Jenkins installed on your Linux server.    
3. Setup a Pipeline script (Jenkins) to deploy the code whenever there is a new commit to your GitHub branch.    


If you need help with Jenkins Pipeline script, then please let me know.

If you don't have time to learn Jenkins now, then just have you code in GitHub repository. Pull it directly in you Linux server and build Jar file in the server itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your last suggestion is great but I didn't find enough resources to learn how to build Jar file in the server itself. All I know is how to build it using an EDI like IntelliJ or Eclipse which is impossible on my small server. Can you suggest how to do it (the tools, links) in few words. :)

Comment: It is provided in the end of all [Sprig boot guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service#_build_an_executable_jar). Depending on your build tool (Maven OR Gradle)  follow the commands there. If you are using maven, execute `./mvnw clean package`.

Comment: I thought it was more complicated than that. But it's something I never tried before. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the jar file contents using `jar xf` command, replace the file and then package it again using `jar cvf` command. 
This is simply doing unzip, changing the old file with uploaded one and again compressing it.

Comment: After using jar cvf the resulting jar wasn't executing anymore. What worked for me is jar uf command which updates the file you want without extracting the initial jar file. Link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html